# import function in c using extern keywod

Tags: c, function, import, extern

I am having problem with importing external function to a main c file.

Here is my minimal code:

```
/* main.c */

#include<stdio.h>
extern int func() 

int main(){
    extern int func();
}

/*external file with one function that I want to     
import*/

#include<stdio.h>

int func(){
    printf("Hello World Again\n");
}
```

I compile and run like this - **gcc main.c** and then **./a.out** but nothing is happening.
Any idea ?

Comment: You're not calling anything, you're declaring the existence of a function. An you're `main()` isn't returning a value, by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to compile the file containing `func` also

```
gcc -Wall main.c external_file.c
```

(Note that the `-Wall` in the compiler command isn't absolutely necessary but is very good practice)

As noted by others, you also need to fix your code to call `func` rather than just re-declaring it.

Answer (score 2):

Because you only **declared** the function, You never called it!

```
extern int func();
```

Declares a function. To call it you must have:

```
int main()
{
   func();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just declaring again in main function..

you need to call the function to work..#include

```
extern int func() 

int main(){
    func();
}

/*external file with one function that I want to     
import*/

#include<stdio.h>

int func(){
    printf("Hello World Again\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edits:  question has changed.

`extern` is only used for external variables.  You just need a prototype for the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(void);    /* <-- prototype */

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    func();

    return 0;
}

void func(void){
    printf("Hello World Again\n");
}
```

Notice a few things.  A prototype of `int func()` means *no parameter checking* in C - this is different to C++.  Also, you are not returning anything from the function, so I replace it with `void func(void)`

Comment: Extern is used for variables and functions both. But the function prototype `void func (void);` happens to be identical to `extern void func (void)`, the extern keyword is implicit in the first case. Strictly speaking, C only allows two kinds of functions: they either have internal or external linkage, corresponding to the keywords static and extern. But extern is default for function prototypes, so you need not write it.

Comment: @Lundin: yes, correct.  But I did say "is only used for external variables", not "can only be used".  The OP appeared to misunderstand C code structure, which `extern` would only further confuse.